# Getting popuptemplate from feature layer to pop up when selecting row from table using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, popup, esri-javascript-api

Using esri javascript api 4.3 in an Angular 2 application.
I initially generate the map using this code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.map = new Map({
        basemap: 'streets',
    });

    this.map.layers.add(new FeatureLayer({
        url: 'http://test/arcgis/rest/services/Project_map/MapServer/0', 
        id: '0',
        visible: true,
        outFields: ["*"],
        popupTemplate: this.jobsTemplate
    }));

    this.view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: this.map,
        center: new Point({
            x: -111.876,
            y: 40.758,
        }),
        zoom: 12,
        rotation: 0
    });
}
```

When a feature on the map is clicked I get a popup containing the values for that feature.  That works fine.

There is also a table that has a row for each feature on the map.

When a table row is clicked, I execute the following code, passing into it the lat and long for that feature:

```
zoomToPoint(zoomLong: number, zoomLat: number) {
    this.view.center = new Point({ x: zoomLong, y: zoomLat });
    this.view.zoom = 15;
    this.view.popup.open({ location: this.view.center });
}
```

I get a popup at the correct location.  But, the popup is empty.
I want it to use the popupTemplate assigned to the feature layer and containing the values for the feature at that location.  Just like what happens if I click on the feature.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#open you have to either specify -along with the location- the title and content to the popup, or the features of the selected point.

```
this.view.popup.open({ location: this.view.center, title: 'foo', content: 'bar' });
```

or

```
this.view.popup.open({ location: this.view.center, features: [selectedGraphic]});
```